# How to find out if dask worker is idle?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am using dask distributed. I have a dask cluster running on AWS. I would like to shutdown workers if they are idle. How do I find out if the dask worker is idle? I have access to the client

```
    from xxxxxx.distributed.ecscluster import EcsCluster
    from dask.distributed import Client
    
    cpu_cluster = EcsCluster(workers=1)
    client = Client(cpu_cluster)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dask-labextension](https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension) to access cluster visualizations and identify workers that are idle.

You can also plug into the Dask [adaptive scaling](https://coiled.io/blog/under-the-hood-with-dasks-cluster-autoscaling/) APIs which are designed to spin down idle nodes.

Comment: I wanted to shutdown idle workers at the end of the day. It had to be automated. dask-labextension seems manual. Adaptive scaling didn't work for me with a custom cluster class. I ended up using retire_workers api call instead. `client.retire_workers()`